Как суммировать значения всех input и вывести их в поле для суммы? Полей для сумм несколько
<div class="input__wrapper">
    <input type="number" class="sum" value=""> - тут сумма
    <input type="number" class="input-small" value="2">
    <input type="number" class="input-small" value="5">
    <input type="number" class="input-small" value="3">
</div>
<div class="input__wrapper">
    <input type="number" class="sum" value=""> - тут сумма
    <input type="number" class="input-small" value="2">
    <input type="number" class="input-small" value="5">
    <input type="number" class="input-small" value="3">
</div>
<div class="input__wrapper">
    <input type="number" class="sum" value=""> - тут сумма
    <input type="number" class="input-small" value="2">
    <input type="number" class="input-small" value="5">
    <input type="number" class="input-small" value="3">
</div>


Для этого вам нужно использовать js или jquery, покажите пример того что Вы написали, и, я подскажу что нужно поправить.

достаточно всего лишь в качестве обёрток использовать <form> вместо <div> и присыпать всё это безобразие сабмитами по вкусу :3
например вот так...


<form onsubmit='this.result.value =
parseInt(this.a.value) + parseInt(this.b.value) + parseInt(this.c.value)'>
  <input type='number' value='1' name='a'>
  <input type='number' value='2' name='b'>
  <input type='number' value='3' name='c'>
  <input type='submit' value='посчитать'>
  <input type='number' value='0' name='result'>
</form>

<form onsubmit='this.result.value =
parseInt(this.a.value) + parseInt(this.b.value) + parseInt(this.c.value)'>
  <input type='number' value='4' name='a'>
  <input type='number' value='7' name='b'>
  <input type='number' value='5' name='c'>
  <input type='submit' value='посчитать'>
  <input type='number' value='0' name='result'>
</form>



но разумеется, писать код инлайном(в аргументах), далеко не самая наилучшая идея.
